# Hexagone lattices

Tags: python

I want to create a hexagonal lattice using the NetworkX python library. But it should be centered basically the whole lattice is a central hexagon and then layers of hexagon around

Comment: _like shown in the figure_ - Which figure are you referring to?

Answer (score 0):

In python with NetworkX you would want to use the hexagonal_lattice_graph function which is part of it's generators class.

Something like this:

```
import networkx as nx
G = nx.generators.lattice.hexagonal_lattice_graph(2,2)
nx.draw(G)
```

Will give a graph which you'd want:
[2x2 lattice output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tYZqv.png)

Comment: Thanks for answering, but what I want is: 

K=1 I get the first hexagon. Let us called it white.
K=2 I get two hexagon, white+red
K=3 I get three white +red+ blue 

And so on

Comment: @PéguyKem if you replace the (2,2) with (number of rows, number of columns) that will give you the K number you want, K = 3 would just be (1,3).

Comment: Thanks, I am definitely satisfied.

Comment: @PéguyKem great! could you accept this as a valid answer, thanks!

Comment: Please, What if I want all those hexagon to have the same size =1

Comment: What if hi want the first hexagons k=1, with side 1 and centre at the origin?

Comment: I want regular hexagon, with size 1.

Comment: The problem is that I want those hexagons to be regular with side 1.